# count 'last children' from any point in javascript object/array structure

Tags: javascript, recursion

I've got a data set simplified to the following

```
var data = {
  foo: 'bar'
  children: [
    {
      foo: 'bar'
      children: [ 
        { foo: 'bar' }, // count
        { foo: 'bar' }, // count
        {
          foo: 'bar'
          children: [
            { foo: 'bar' }, // count
            { foo: 'bar' }, // count
          ]
        },
        { foo: 'bar' }, // count
      ]
    },
    {
      // etc
    }
  ]
}
```

There's a lot more of it than that. Any number of objects below nested.

```
{
  foo: 'bar'
  children: []
}
```

I want to be able to calculate the total 'last children' of any 'node' in the structure. So far I have written a quick script that will work it out from the top level using a counter variable scoped outside of the recursing function - but that stop it being re-usable.

```
var total = 0;

var countLastChildren = function(object) {

  if(object.children) {
    object.children.forEach(function(el){
      countLastChildren(el);
    }); 
  } else {
    total++;
  }
}
countLastChildren(data);
console.log(total);
```

I can't quite get my head round how to scope the counter inside countLastChildren() to allow it to return a value and make it re-usable by passing in different objects or objects nested within my main structure.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: If `data` is the structure shown, what would be the desired result from `countLastChildren(data)`? 7 (all the children of the top-most level), or 2 (just the lowest level children), or...?

Comment: I've added some comments to show where I'd like to 'count'. It's basically count all objects without children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just have the function return the count:

```
var countLastChildren = function(object) {

    if(object.children) {
        var return_val = 0;
        object.children.forEach(function(el){
            return_val += countLastChildren(el);
        });
        return return_val; 
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
console.log(countLastChildren(data));
```

Comment: Ah that's right, I thought I was missing something simple. It's hard to visualise recursion (particularly including return values) sometimes

Comment: Marking this one as accepted since it points out a good change in my original code :) Probly easiest to follow for a googler too

Answer (score 2):

Some code golf:

```
function Total(obj) {
      return obj.children 
      ? obj.children.map(Total).reduce(function (prev, cur) { return prev + cur; }) 
      : 1;
}
```

Comment: really like that. in fact really like any use of map/reduce :-) can confirm that works on my full set of data. Would need underscore or something if used in the browser though